# Chrome Bug - onDOMContentLoaded firing before any DOM has loaded

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have set up an event listener in my background.js file:

```
chrome.webNavigation.onDOMContentLoaded.addListener(function (info) {
    // Checks for the URL bar navigation and not any child frames
    if (info.frameId === 0){
        var url = info.url;
        console.log('visit: ' + url);
    }
});
```

I would expect the a log entry showing the url of the current page when the dom has loaded. The problem arises when typing in a search in the omnibox. Say I visit www.twitter.com often enough to have it cached when I enter a search that starts with "t" in the omnibox.

If I enter the search term "testing123" in the omnibox, I'll see a log entry saying "visit: http://www.twitter.com/". The same thing will happen if I enter the search term "callbacks": I'll see a log entry saying "visit: http://www.cnn.com" These get logged even before I hit enter on the search. I'm assuming this is because Chrome is doing some sort of pre-fetching on commonly visited URLs, but I still think this is unexpected behavior.

Can someone confirm? Thanks.

**Edit:**
I tried some other webNavigation methods but I'm still seeing some inconsistencies:

`onComitted` - Fired almost all the time. 
`onHistoryStateUpdated` - Fired some of the time 
`onTabReplaced` - Was not firing as no pre-rendering was done.

**Edit 2:**
The following code helped me sort out events that were being fired on inactive tabs. (See comments 5/6 for more explanation.)

```
chrome.webNavigation.onCommitted.addListener(
    function (info) {

        // Checks for the URL bar navigation and not any child frames
        if (info.frameId === 0){

            chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function (tab) {
                // Ensures that the listener is only attached to the active tab
                if (tab[0].id === info.tabId){
                    // Everything's good! Do your work here
                }
            });
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: Could be pre-rendering. What if you add a [`chrome.webNavigation.onTabReplaced`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation#event-onTabReplaced) event listener? I guess that you'll see that the onDOMContentLoaded events match the latter events.

Comment: So you're suggesting wrapping the onDomContentLoaded listener within the onTabReplaced? I understand that the onTabReplaced event should be fired less frequently, but I'd still need the url, frameId, etc. info from the onDOMContentLoaded event.

Comment: No, I suggest to use that event to find out whether the issue is really caused by pre-rendering. And perhaps ignore the event if the onTabReplaced event occurs.

Comment: I guess it's not pre-rendering. The onTabReplaced event is never fired during my same use case as above. Might this be a bug worth reporting?

Comment: `onTabReplaced` would only fire if you actually opened the URL and it was pre-rendered, if I understand it correctly. You should check `info.tabId` for those "extra" events you're seeing.

Comment: Matching the tabId of the webNavigation event to that of the active tab ID is what finally helped me sift out the undesirable events. I'm still not sure why they're firing though. I did submit a bug report: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=391038
I've also edited my original post with the code that matches the tab ID's.